# Wi-Fi Network is not showing network list

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new Linux user, so just after installing it I faced my first problem and now I am trying to solve it.
The problem is that there's no network list available on Wi-Fi network.

As I live in rural area (there isn't any Wi-Fi network except mine own), I thought firstly that it doesn't want to show my Wi-Fi, but after that I turned on Hotspot from my mobile device and it didn't even listed that one. After realising that I tried to add it manually, but also that didn't work.

I am currently using USB Tethering to access the internet.

If anyone has idea on how to solve this, I'd appriciate your help!

Here's some general info, from console:

```
str1ng@str1ng:~$ uname -a
Linux str1ng 5.8.0-55-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 08:55:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlo1
                version: 00
                serial: 00:24:d6:2e:47:16
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 5000-5.uco latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:36 memory:da100000-da101fff
```

If you need any other information please let me know, I will provide it for you.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
str1ng@str1ng:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -e wlo -e iwl
[   14.582736] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   16.073578] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 5000-5.ucode op_mode iwldvm
[   16.717577] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   17.580718] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   17.580720] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   17.580722] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   17.580724] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
[   17.629776] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   17.633721] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   36.296301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   36.422637] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

EDIT 2:

```
str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ sudo iwlist wlo1 scan
[sudo] password for str1ng: 
wlo1      No scan results

str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ sudo iwlist wlo0 scan
wlo0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

EDIT 3:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID        MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       DC:F8:B9:9E:3A:EF  SmajkanNET  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  61      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 

IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 



str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ sudo iwlist wlo1 freq
wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -e wlo -e iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've edited and updated my question with results of command your required. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please also show us: `rfkill list all` and: `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan`. Is this a dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: @chili555 Okay, I just updated the question. And no, this is not dual-boot with Windows.
Btw. I just bought new external WiFi adapter - see this question: [refer to a link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344099/wifi-network-is-not-showing-on-wifi-network-list-when-i-use-laptops-wifi)

Comment: With the USB attached, please show us: `nmcli device wifi list` and: sudo iwlist wlo1 freq` Your new question is essentially the same as this and may be closed.

Comment: @chili555 Again, I've just updated question with commands you asked me for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126138/discussion-between-chili555-and-str1ng).