# WiFi network is not showing on WiFi network list when I use laptop's WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers

So after already posting question, which you can refer to on this link:
[Refer to question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343971/wi-fi-network-is-not-showing-network-list) - which is once again to say laptop's built-in device/WiFi adapter.

I decided to buy new WiFi adapter and to test it if it's going to show network list, so I bought TP-LINK's TL-WN722N. I just inserted it in on one of the laptop's USB ports and it's working perfectly, it successfully showed my Network on network list

[image]

As you can see there are two devices Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN - which is laptop's device, and the other one Qualcomm Atheros AR9721 - which is new device/WiFi adapter which I just inserted in.

My concern here's why does my laptop's Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN doesn't show any available Networks? Can it be hardware related problem, I mean, last night I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu, and on Windows it was working just fine. Is there anything I can do to check on health of this laptop's device or anything similar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am working to answer this question for you. I suggest that you stick with the original question.

Comment: @chili555 Oh, okay. Sure. I just thought I should open new question regarding to this...

Comment: @str1ng Given the issue is the same, and related to the same problem/system/issue you should stick to one question.